# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i need some help here, this HTTP request failed error was give me a lot of headache. I try in local server and online server but still it didn't work, i trying to export my table data to .PDF or .XLS format. This is my controller.

```
public function export()
{
    $format = Input::query('type');
    $filename = Carbon::now()->format('Ymd_') . "ProductsList";
    $file = Excel::create($filename, function ($excel) {

        $excel->sheet('Product Cost and Amount', function ($sheet) {
            $sheet->setfitToPage(0);
            $sheet->setfitToWidth(0);
            $sheet->setfitToHeight(0);
            $sheet->freezeFirstRowAndColumn();
            $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
            $products = $this->report->getProductLevels();
            $sheet->loadView('reports.product_report.product_level_report', compact('products'));

        });

        $excel->sheet('Product Locations', function ($sheet) {
            $sheet->setfitToPage(0);
            $sheet->setfitToWidth(0);
            $sheet->setfitToHeight(0);
            $sheet->freezeFirstRowAndColumn();
            $products = $this->report->getProductLevels();
            $sheet->loadView('reports.product_report.product_warehouse_level', compact('products'));

        });


    });
```

This my views

```
<html>
{{ HTML::style('dist/css/table.css') }}
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<body>
<!-- Headings -->
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Reorder Amount</th>
    <th>Unit Cost</th>
    <th>Selling Cost</th>
    <th>Tax rate</th>
    <th>Category</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php $i = 1; ?>
@foreach($products as $product)
    <tr>
        <td scope="row">{{$i}}</td>
        <td><b>{{$product->productName}}</b></td>
        <td>{{$product->amount}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->reorderAmount}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->unitCost}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->sellingCost}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->productTaxRate}}%</td>
        <td>{{$product->categoryName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
</body>
</html>
```

I'm stuck with this in a few hours and still can't solve this. I'm glad if someone willing to help me, thank you for your attention

Comment: I don't see where you're making an HTTP request.

Comment: Loading any web page is a request, Halcyon.

Comment: Can you add what does the log file says?

Comment: `public function export()` seems irrelevant to me. It's not used anywhere and does not have any obvious side-effects.

Comment: @apokryfos this is my log files http://pasted.co/d2b1d98c and i'm using Maatwebsite for exporting .xls and .pdf files.

Comment: @AlfredWoo this is my log says http://pasted.co/d2b1d98c

Comment: The log says that it can't find your stylesheet (.css) file. Check your paths, make sure it's in `/public/dist/css/table.css` (though you may want to move it to `/public/css/dist/table/css` as it seems more reasonable).

Comment: @apokryfos .css file is right in it's place, check this out http://162.144.36.40:8000/dist/css/table.css i'm running the server, so you can see it yourself.

Comment: @irvansandoval the link you provided prints 404 page

Comment: @AlfredWoo i'm sorry, please check again, i'm moving the file recently.